# Web services size exceeded

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using WCF service to get some documents from another server, it works perfect until I try them with a 50MB or above document.

I looked at the size of file before sending it back through WCF service,
[image]

My WCF web.config on server settings is,

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="eShare_BasicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and in client code where its calling WCF service to get file is,

```
  BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding( );
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536232;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
```

**Error**

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536232) has
>   been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual content length of the message on the wire, using Fiddler or similar. There are some things that will affect the size of the message compared to the size of the document (e.g. encoding, encryption, SOAP envelope etc.). I guess you will find the overhead of that will tip your actual message size over the limit.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin I would but honestly I don't see any reason for how it adds an extra of 13MB with file content really :/

Comment: I agree, it seem unlikely, but it would presumably help to see exactly what's happening under the hood since it is very easy to do. I didnt put this as an answer just for the reason you said :o)